# If a load balancer pings a dead server, what happens to the previous requests? How do we avoid losing requests sent to the dead server?

Tags: server, request, load-balancing

I'm trying to write my own webserver (like NGINX or Apache) as a learning exercise. It can perform as a forward and reverse proxy, and now I want to add some load-balancing logic to it.

So a load balancer distributes requests across an array of servers, and when a server dies, it routes requests away from the dead server to the live ones.

To check the health of a server, we commonly ping it, and mark it as dead if we can't connect. (Correct me if this is wrong).

This means there is a delay between the server *dying*, and us *finding out* about it's death. In the meantine, we've routed requests to the dead server. What happens to them? How do we retrieve them? (Do we retrieve them at all, or just timeout and hope the client retries?)

If the server could communicate with the load balancer (i.e. notify on start, notify on stop), this can be avoided, but how can we avoid unexpected failures? What's the "canonical" way to do health-checks?

Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: Pinging the server isn't exactly how Nginx does health checks, at least for passive ones which are available in free Nginx. Once connections to a backend server fail, the server will be dropped from the active backend pool:  https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/http-load-balancer/#passive-health-checks

Comment: Ah, so pinging the server is an active check - this gives me some terminology to google, cheers! So Nginx tries to send a request, and if it fails, we mark the server as unavailable and wait `x` seconds, and then continually repeat this process? Is that correct?

Comment: Pretty much, thats how I understand it. You could set up a nginx instance and a failing backend instance to play around with, that should give you some insight into how it works.